# c#: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, list, object

This is part of my code.

```
List<DateTime>[] newarraydate1 = new List<DateTime>[70];
DateTime temp1 = arraydate1[k][aa];
newarraydate1[k].Add(temp1);
```

I used messagebox.show(temp1) and there is a value in temp1. The error is shown on the first line of program.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an array, you create only the containing structure. Its members are initializeded to their default values, which in case of `List<DateTime>` is `null`. Essentially, you get seventy `null` references, each one capable of holding a list of `DateTime`.

To fix this, you should either assign new arrays in a loop

```
List<DateTime>[] newarraydate1 = new List<DateTime>[70];
for (int i = 0 ; i != newarraydate1.Length ; i++) {
    newarraydate1[i] = new List<DateTime>();
}
```

or use LINQ:

```
List<DateTime>[] newarraydate1 = Enumerable
    .Range(0, 70)
    .Select(n => new List<DateTime>())
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring an array of `List<DateTime>` but never creating any actual instances of List within that array. You need to modify your code this way:

```
List<DateTime>[] newarraydate1 = new List<DateTime>[70];
for(int i=0;i<70;i++)
    newarraydate1[i]=new List<DateTime>();
DateTime temp1 = arraydate1[k][aa];
newarraydate1[k].Add(temp1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's on purpose you create an *array* of *lists* of `DateTime`s, you must first create each list in the entry with

```
newarraydate1[k] = new List<DateTime>();
```

Only then can you `Add` to the `k`th list (as in the last code line of your question).